# Swagger inheritance in objects

Tags: documentation, swagger

I want to document some wrapped json documents:

```
  Action:
    required:
      - description
      - name
    properties:
      description:
        type: string
        format: string
      name:
        type: string
        format: string
  Actor:
    required:
      - gpn
    properties:
      gpn:
        type: string
        format: string
  Object:
    required:
      - image
      - type
      - url
    properties:
      image:
        type: string
        format: string
      type:
        type: string
        format: string
      url:
        type: string
        format: string
  CreateActivity:
    required:
      - action
      - actor
      - object
      - title
      - externalID
    properties:
      action:
        $ref: Action
      actor:
        $ref: Actor
      object:
        $ref: Object
      title:
        type: string
        format: string
      externalID:
        type: string
        format: string
```

And I have declared this with a `$ref` in Swagger

paths:

```
  /activity:
    get:
      description: Returns an activity
      operationId: fetchActivity
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: externalActivityID
          in: query
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: existing activity
          schema:
            $ref: CreateActivity
        default:
          description: unexpected error
          schema:
            $ref: ErrorModel
```

The result isn't what im excepting (and i copyied the approach from pet shop). I want a object with linked entries (i.e. Action, Actor and Object are in CreateActivity with field names) and linked the request to the CreateActivity Object.

Screenshots are showing the actual situation:

the Object with the missing "subobjects"

[image: object in swagger]

And the missing link in the swagger documentation:

[image: missing link]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: See _How to address a question asking about a bugged feature in a product?_ (Dup of close reason.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with swagger-editor.

Please take a look here - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/217.

Also, when you use `"type": "string"`, there's no need to add `"format":"string"` as it adds no information to it. The `"format"` field is used to finely define the `"type"`.

Comment: thanks, i'll change this. is there a workaround until the fix is ready?

Comment: Not that I know. It shouldn't really affect your work directly though, as the editor is used for building your API documentation, not to display it. The preview pane is more of a convenience to see that your API is displaying as expected. You can still use swagger-ui to display your spec correctly.

Comment: [Resolved Dec 19 2014](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/217#issuecomment-67681964).